# What is causing "Redis commands must be called within the context of a connection to a Redis Server"?

Tags: clojure, redis

I'm trying to run this code, but am getting the error in the post title.

------------------ core.clj ----------------

```
(def server-conn  {:pool {} :spec {:host "myhost.com" :port 12345 }} )

 (defmacro wcar* [& body] `(car/wcar server-conn ~@body))

(defn run-redis-test1 [& args]

  (wcar* 
       (car/set "foo" "bar")
       (car/get "foo")
   )
     ;; ---------------- this was the problem  (car/get "foo") OUTSIDE the (wcar*
     **(def g (car/get "foo")) ; -> ["PONG" "OK" "bar"]
     (pr "(outside war) gg1" gg1)**   
)

(defn -main  [& args]
  (run-redis-test1)
)
```

Comment: This error usually appears when you're executing redis commands (e.g. `car/ping`, `car/set`, `car/get`) outside of `wcar/car` scope, but your code looks fine. The only error in your code I can see is an extra `server-conn` (you're passing it to `car/wcar` twice).

Comment: By the way, it's a very bad practice to use `defmacro` inside a function. If you want to register a macro, do it on the top level.

Comment: Solved !...  I had forgotten to pasted in the real problem code, which was the (car/get "foo") OUTSIDE the (wcar*

And actually the "double" server-conn, while superfluous, doesn't seem to cause any problem.

Comment: @Leonid, Ya, of course you were right, and I added the code that was the cause.

I have literally only a couple of days  of clojure experience, and I couldn't tell at first where the "context of a connection ..." was occuring.

There are NO code examples in the repo for this library, I only got this by requesting it and had to figure out how to "fit" it into a "lein" format.